# Sql Server - Run job which contains dtsx that creates files in a remote folder in another server

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

I am doing a SSIS dtsx file in which I access data in Dynamics CRM. This is the procedure: 
* Someone copies files in a folder (.txt files from OCR, that's an external process).
* The SSIS grabs those files and copy them to another folder "Processed". Then the SSIS looks for data in those .txt and creates records for entities in Dynamics CRM. 
* When some record can´t be created on CRM, it is an Error and the SSIS creates a temporal table in SQLServer with the error. Then the SSIS creates some .txt files which show all the errors, the number of the row and name of the original file.

I could run it from the Visual Studio, but I am not able to run it from a job. I've followed those steps: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14401/How-to-Schedule-and-Run-a-SSIS-package-DTS-Job-in , but still not running.

What may I do to  handle this? 
The dtsx in the job is in a SQL  server and the files which I want to work with are in a CRM server.

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally ir worked!! 
I followed the steps again and I could run the job successfully.